# Creating a key for box plot mean and median lines in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, boxplot, legend-properties

I have the following code which creates a box plot of APOE4 gene copies and memory scores (hence the variable names)

```
clean_merged.boxplot('composite scores', by='APOE4', widths = 0.8, showmeans = True, meanline = True)
plt.title('Mean Composite Memory Score by APOE4 Copies')
plt.xlabel('Number of APOE4 Copies')
plt.ylabel('Composite Memory Score')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,10)
```

which generates this output:

[image]
I would like to add a legend for the mean (green dashed) and median lines  (solid fill) and am struggling to do so based on previously asked questions as how i have created my graph is quite different to the methods usually advised.

I'm new to python so any help is appreciated :) thanks !!!

Answer (score 4):

You can add "empty" lines to the plot, assigning them the appropriate styles, colors, and labels. These will be picked up by `plt.legend()`. Since I don't have your data, I'm using seaborn's Titanic dataset as an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
titanic.boxplot('age', by='sex', widths=0.8, showmeans=True, meanline=True)

plt.plot([], [], '-', linewidth=1, color='Crimson', label='mean')
plt.plot([], [], '-', linewidth=1, color='gray', label='median')

plt.legend()
```

[image: arbitrary legend]

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for! i worked out you can use `'--'` to make a dashed line in the legend as well which works perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help.